# Roku video prewiew method

Tags: roku, brightscript

We have rowlist where there is list of video data and when it focused on any item can we show preview of that item after certain period of time by popup?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct preview facility in roku. But it is possible to show preview, although little bit tricky.

1. When the row item is focused, start a timer for the specified time.
2. On time period completion, start playing the video. play the video for whatever duration you want, and stop it after that. Video play and stop, both can be handled using a single timer.
3. If you want to reduce the height and width of video player, reduce it using "***width***" and "***height***" field. Also you can change the position of video using "***translation***" field.
4. Don't forget to reset these fields to default value (all set to 0), when closing the preview.